Most basic "bring your own data" query in GQL
In SQL, I can write a query that already includes the data such as the following:
SELECT 1

Or, with a slightly less trivial example:
WITH users as (
    SELECT 1 id, "tom" name UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, "sandra" name
) SELECT * FROM users

Is there a similar way to do this in GQL without having to have already-defined tables? If so, what would be a bare-bones example?
GRAPH (...inline table... ?)
MATCH
  (from_person:Person {name: "Dana"})-[:Owns]->
RETURN
  from_person.name 


What is the usecase?

@RyoMatsuzaka practicing/mocking up various queries without having to have real-data that is stored.

Ok. What kind of GQL, are you using now?

@RyoMatsuzaka currently Cloud Spanner.

Ok, I will consider it.

You cannot use GQL with Cloud Spanner. You mean Google Cloud Service, right?

@RyoMatsuzaka yes you can: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/graph-intro

I don't think there are inline tables in GQL. But, you can maybe create temp in-memory data using unwind to mimic inline data to use in the query.
WITH [
{id: 1, name: 'Tom'},
{id: 2, name: 'Sandra'}
] AS users

UNWIND users AS user
MATCH (from_person:Person {name: "Dana"})-[:Owns]->()
RETURN from_person.name, user.id, user.name


Thanks, what dialect is that in (does it work?)

it's cypher

Since Cloud Spanner's GQL doesn't support inline data defs within queries, you can create temporary tables using a WITH CTE to define inline data.
-- Define inline data using Common Table Expressions
WITH
  Persons AS (
    SELECT 'tom' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sandra' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dana' AS name
  ),
  Owns AS (
    SELECT 'Dana' AS owner_name, 'Item1' AS item_name
  )

-- Construct a graph using the inline data
GRAPH g AS
(
  -- Create Person nodes
  SELECT name
  FROM Persons
  LABEL Person
),

-- Create Owns relationships
(
  SELECT owner.name AS from_node,
         item.name AS to_node,
         'Owns' AS edge_type
  FROM Persons owner
  JOIN Owns ON owner.name = Owns.owner_name
  JOIN Persons item ON item.name = Owns.item_name
)

-- Query the graph
MATCH
  (from_person:Person {name: 'Dana'})-[:Owns]->(item)
RETURN
  from_person.name;

